# How to prove the inequality on relative entropy?

Tags: inequality, entropy

[image: the definition of relative entropy]

Here is the definition of Relative Entropy
Now I am only interested in the simplest condition that the index set is finite and discrete, as the naive probability distribution vectors.

Now if the distribution vector 
$p_3=a p_1+(1-a) p_2$, $q_3=a q_1+(1-a)q_2$ for $0<a<1$
how to prove that $H(p1|q1)<H(p3|q3)<H(p2|q2)$?

Answer (score 0):

The right hand side can be proved with the joint convexity of relative entropy,
that is,

```
H(\sum_{i}c_i P_i||\sum_i c_iQ_i)\leq \sum_i c_i H(P_i||Q_i)
```

the left hand side is not valid as I see. For example, suppose `P_1=Q_2=(0.3,0.7),P_2=Q_1={0.7,0.3}`, and `a=0.5`, then the middle term vanishes while the left side is positive.

Comment: How to prove the convexity?